# How to show the Windows 10 task bar in fullscreen applications?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

How do I show the task bar when an application is running in full screen? E.g. with VLC or Youtube in full screen mode.

I would like the task bar to become visible when I move the cursor to the edge where the Taskbar is located. Like in macOS with the Dock.

Comment: My answer was downvoted and I have no idea why. Hiding the Task Bar works for me all the time.

Comment: You suggested to enable "auto hide taskbar" in taskbar's settings. This doesn't allow to show the task bar while in fullscreen mode. I tried a fullscreen YouTube window and moving my mouse to the edge. The taskbar kept being hidden.

Comment: Works for me for the apps I tried. I did not try You Tube - maybe it is misbehaved.  Now I just loaded a You Tube, clicked on full screen and hidden task bar comes up just fine. If I undelete my answer, will you remove your downvote?